# Assign to object within map

Tags: javascript, loops

I'd like to assign to an object within an array map

Heres the array of objects I want to add to

```
const arr = [
 {
  "key": "Mike",
  "ref": 11800
 },
 {
  "key": "Raph",
  "ref": 9339
 },
 {
  "key": "Leo",
  "ref": 2560
 },
]
```

I want to add add a new property to the object called `slug` while I loop over it like below. Possibly `map` is not the right function to use here because `ESLINT` complains about assigning within the map.

```
arr.map((item) => {
  ...item,
  item.slug = `${item.key.toLowerCase();}/${String(item.ref)}`
});
```

Comment: Callbacks passed into `Array`'s _functional_ methods, like  `map` and `filter` should not have side-effects, hence the ESLINT warning. Is this for a Redux Reducer function?

Comment: Instead of `item.slug =` maybe you want `slug:`?

Comment: Change `item.slug = ` to `slug:` since your creating a new object property. Also, wrap `{}` in parenthesis `({})` so it's not interpreted as a function body but rather as an object literal

Comment: @NickParsons The OP said they want to set `.slug` on the existing `item` rather than returning a new object.

Comment: @Dai I didn't interpret it that way, but then yeah, map isn't the right tool here. (Maybe the OP is happy with creating a new array of objects, not sure though)

Comment: OP should clarify I guess. If map is the right function, it also needs an assignment on the left `let newArr = arr.map(...etc`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

.map() returns a new array containing the results of calling provided function for each element, so you should assign it to the new variable:

```js
const arr = [{
    "key": "Mike",
    "ref": 11800
  },
  {
    "key": "Raph",
    "ref": 9339
  },
  {
    "key": "Leo",
    "ref": 2560
  },
]

const newArr = arr.map(item => ({
  ...item,
  slug: `${item.key.toLowerCase()}/${String(item.ref)}`
}))

console.dir(newArr)
```

If you want to add something to existing objects within an array you should use a for loop or .forEach():

```js
const arr = [{
    "key": "Mike",
    "ref": 11800
  },
  {
    "key": "Raph",
    "ref": 9339
  },
  {
    "key": "Leo",
    "ref": 2560
  },
]

arr.forEach(item => {
  item.slug = `${item.key.toLowerCase()}/${String(item.ref)}`
})

console.dir(arr)
```

Answer (score 3):

When mutating an array, or perform operations with side-effects, you should use a `for` loop or the `Array.prototype.forEach` method. If you want to perform *pure functional* operations over an array, then use `Array.prototype.filter`, `Array.prototype.map`, etc.

If you want to *set* a new property on the existing array elements then do this:

```
const arr = [ { key: "Mike", ref: 11800 }, /*etc*/ ];

for( const e of arr ) {
    e.slug = e.key.toLowerCase() + "/" + e.ref.toString();
}
```

If you want to generate a new array with new members, then do this:

```
const arr = [ { key: "Mike", ref: 11800 }, /*etc*/ ];

// Note the parentheses within `map` to avoid ambiguous syntax:
const newArr = arr.map( e => ( { slug: e.key.toLowerCase() + "/" + e.ref.toString() } ) );

console.log( newArr ); // [ { slug: "mike/11800" } ]
```

Alternatively, to copy over all properties and then add new properties use `Object.assign`:

```
const arr = [ { key: "Mike", ref: 11800 }, /*etc*/ ];

const newArr = arr.map( e => Object.assign( {}, e, { slug: e.key.toLowerCase() + "/" + e.ref.toString() } ) );

console.log( newArr ); // [ { key: "Mike", ref: 11800, slug: "mike/11800" } ]
```